# How can I use Twitter4J in open source without exposing my oauth secret tokens?

Tags: java, eclipse, open-source, twitter4j

I have a Java app that generates pictures for a user.  I'd like to then offer to post these pictures to that user's twitter account.

My app is also open source, which means I can't use OAuth because then my secret tokens will be plainly visible in the source code on github.

Am I using the wrong library?  Is there another way?

Thank you!

Comment: when it were closed source, you couldn't securely hide the token either. You could make it harder to find it, but it's impossible to make it impossible to find out.

Comment: Not relevant, but thank you for being thorough.

Answer (score 0):

When you want the users to post to twitter using their accounts, there is no reason to include any information about your own account in the sourcecode of the program.

Instead of that you should prompt the user to enter their own username and password when they install the application. The application should then save these to a local file.

Answer (score 0):

You cant do that without exposing your secret tokens.